# tmux: How to display line numbers in copy-mode?

Tags: terminal, tmux

After entering copy-mode in tmux using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, I can goto a line using <kbd>:</kbd>. However, I cannot see line-numbers.

How can I enable line-numbers only in copy-mode? I don't want it enabled in normal mode.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a tmux expert, but perhaps you could improve on this idea: split the pane in two side-by-side and show a list of decreasing numbers in the new pane which ends at 0 for the lowest line.  For example, in your `~/.tmux.conf` set a binding for character `=`

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi = split-window -h -p 90 'seq 24 -1 1;sleep 15'\;  swap-pane -dU
```

Then in vi copy mode typing `=` will split the current pane, and list numbers 24 to 1 in the new pane for 15 seconds. Since the new pane is put on the right, a `swap-pane` moves it to the left.

Comment: +1 this is really useful to see line numbers in shell, I'm now using it with a set of hotkeys to pull text from the current tmux pane, e.g. output of a previous command without needing to rerun it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, I top up the goto-line binding: (Gnome Terminal)

```bash
# Override's goto-line key binding to display a temporary number of lines on the side.
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi : run "tmux split-window -h -l 3 -b 'while [ \$SECONDS -lt 10 ]; do seq $(tput lines) -1 1; sleep 1; clear; done'; tmux last-pane; sleep 0.15" \; command-prompt -p "Go to line:" "send-keys -X goto-line %%;"
```

This will overload the goto-line key binding to display a temporary (10 seconds) number of lines on the side, in an ascending order. Place it in your `tmux.conf` and refresh: `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`.